# Periodic boundary solution forms a closed subspace in $H^1$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading the Sobolev spaces chapter in Functional Analysis by Brezis. And there is a statement saying that

$H = \left\{v \in H^1(0,1)| v(0) = v(1) \right\}$ is a closed subspace of $H^1(0,1)$. I am wondering why $v_n \rightarrow v$ in $H^1(0,1)$ and $v_n(0) = v_n(1)$ can conclude that $v(0) = v(1)$.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functional
$$
u \mapsto u(1) - u(0)
$$
is linear and bounded on $H^1(0,1)$. Hence, its kernel is closed and this kernel coincides with the subspace of periodic functions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:
$$v(0) = v(0) - v(1) + v(1) = -\int_0^1 v'dt + v(1) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 v_n' dt + v(1) = v(1),$$
where $v_n', v'$ denote the weak derivatives of $v_n, v$.